# Spring boot 2.7.18 and spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes 1.1.10 'configMapPropertySourceLocator' issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I am trying to upgrade spring boot from 2.5.12 to 2.7.18 and spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes from 1.1.2.RELEASE to 1.1.10.RELEASE.
With old versions I have application running and there is no any issue.
Initially I have following in pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.15</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After update I have

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After update when trying to run I am getting

```
... INFO 1 --- [ main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
... ERROR 1 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configMapPropertySourceLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/config/BootstrapConfiguration$KubernetesPropertySourceConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@299a06ac] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:195) [spring-cloud-context-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7] at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114) [spring-cloud-context-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7] at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:77) [spring-cloud-context-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178) [spring-context-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:171) [spring-context-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) [spring-context-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:133) [spring-context-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18] at com.xylem.dewatering.lms.LmsApplication.main(LmsApplication.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[...-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[...-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[...-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[...-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@299a06ac] at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:417) ~[spring-orm-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:335) ~[spring-orm-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] ... 37 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/fabric8/kubernetes/api/builder/Function at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2729) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2003) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31] ... 43 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.builder.Function at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[...-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_372] ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Can you help with what is missing?

Update versions and get application running.

Comment: Remove `version` tags from the `spring-cloud-starter-*`. You are managing them to an older and incompatible version. The spring-cloud bom (which I assume you are importing as a `dependencyManagement` part) already manages the proper version.

Comment: When removing version it will cause another issue.
```
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config:jar:unknown was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

```

Comment: Remove that dependency as that doesn't seem to exist anymore and has been part of the other dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to remove and leave this 2s

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

but it ended up with 

"nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder..."
it is not able to read property values from config repo

Comment: Again remove the version. As you are pulling in old incompatible versions. Also don't add code as comments.

Comment: @M.Deinum I put the updated version as an answer

Comment: That isn't an answer. rather a new question stating that it doesn't work. I also suspect you need to use one of the other kubernetes starters as they appear to have been split into multiple others. I suspect the `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config` and remove the `kubernetes-client` dependency as that would be included in here. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/2.1.9/reference/html/

Comment: @M.Deinum If I remove version, it will end up with [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes:jar is missing.

Comment: Read, please read... You need a different dependency!.

Answer (score 0):

Having this
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
</dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
...
     </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>
```

...

it results in

```
Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes:pom:unknown in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```